# Export buttons are not appearing in Datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatables

I am using jQuery DataTables 1.10 and all my code is working fine. To add export functionality I refer [this](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/simple.html) link. I have added all the files what is said

```
//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js
https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js
https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.0.3/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js
//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/2.5.0/jszip.min.js
//cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.18/build/pdfmake.min.js
//cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.18/build/vfs_fonts.js
//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.0.3/js/buttons.html5.min.js
//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css
//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.0.3/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css
```

I have downloaded these files and stored locally. So my final code is like :

```
 table = $(".jqueryDataTable").DataTable( {

        "initComplete": function(oSettings, json) {
              alert( 'DataTables has finished its initialisation in table.' );
              this.fnHideEmptyColumns(this);
              $('#lblReportHeader').html(reportHeader);
              $('#lblFromDate').html(fromDateHeader);
              $('#lblToDate').html(fromToHeader);
              $('#tblReportHeader').show();
            },
            "searching": false,
            "retrieve": true, 
            "destroy": true,
            "ajax": "./getReportDetails",
            "jQueryUI": true,
            "dom": 'r<"H"lf><"datatable-scroll"t><"F"ip>',
            buttons: [
                      'copyHtml5',
                      'excelHtml5',
                      'csvHtml5',
                      'pdfHtml5'
                  ],
            "fnServerParams": function ( data ) {
                newData=data;
                newData.push( { "name": "reportType", "value": reportType }, { "name": "reportSubType", "value": reportSubType}, { "name": "fromDate", "value": fromDate}, { "name": "toDate", "value": toDate});
            },
            "columns": [
                            { "mData": "username", "sTitle": "username"},
                            { "mData": "transferType", "sTitle": "transferType"},
                            { "mData": "fromAccount", "sTitle": "fromAccount"}
                ]
        } );
```

But it is not showing any export button on my UI.

[image]

What is the wrong in my code ?

Comment: Works fine **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/ym4wyc3s/)**.. I think since you have copied it to local and gave a local reference something messed up. Try giving the `cdn` files reference itself..

Comment: I think I have problem with my dom, can you correct it ? Like by adding parameter for buttons ?

Comment: This is new version of adding buttons, so sorry to say, since I do not have much idea on this.. and also you have some ajax format to load data.. All that might be part of the issue. Did you try giving `CDN` file source?

Comment: I have changes DOM value to "dom": 'Bfr<"H"lf><"datatable-scroll"t><"F"ip>' and it is showing buttons now but they are not in working state !!!

Comment: I am also facing the same problem. It seems the above questions still haven't any answer yet :(.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issues where everything looked good from adding required javascript and css files to specifying "dom" value and initializing buttons array in the data table body. However, my root cause of not displaying the buttons was that I was adding one of the dependent javascripts two times and same js file was placed in two different locations inside my resources folder. As soon as I identified and remove additional duplicate js reference, the problem got resolved and I was able to see the buttons displayed and working as well.

Answer (score 5):

Here issue is you have included required JS files but at the time of initialization, you haven't specified options for export like mentioned below:

```
 $('#example').DataTable( {
      dom: 'Bfrtip',
      buttons: [
          'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
      ]
  });
```

You can remove the options from **copy**, **csv**, **excel**, **pdf**, **print** according to requirement.

You cannot change the name of button, it needs to be exact same as mentioned.

Comment: Just to be clear, you can change the name of your buttons with the extend option, {extend:'print', 'Print Table'}, and so on